# Have ServiceStack default route go to MVC3 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I've installed `ServiceStack.Host.MVC` into an existing  MVC3 project that has a lot of controllers.

It's now routing to default.htm.  I found another StackOverFlow question that said to change the Default redirect path, do the following.

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {DefaultRedirectPath = "/Foo" });
```

But I really want to change it to execute the default Controller and Action as setup in the global.ascx.  I've edited the DefaultRedirectPath to point at */Home*, and it seems to work fine, and doesn't add Home to my url or anything, but I'm not 100% on the relationship between having an AppHost in my application.

If changing this isn't the right thing to do, what's the best way to get started integrating some Service Stack AppHost in with a regular MVC application.  I'm going to move my base controllers to `ServiceStackController`, and slowly start using the new Session and User management stuff.  Eventually, I'm going to want to use the authorization or shared sessionId with some services, but I'll get to that later.

To start, my goal is to start using some of the IOC functionality of Funq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ServiceStack BootstrapAPI application sets the CatchAllController to be the HomeController of the MVC application. This worked for me.

In the AppHost::Configure, I put the following code:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
  //  Other Configuration constructs here

  ServiceStackController.CatchAllController = reqCtx => container.TryResolve<HomeController>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need DefaultRedirectPath, because it is just a redirect to a predefined URL. You need to have your MVC controllers hit when using your old urls, and have a new URL area for ServiceStack. To do this, [start by setting `ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework). It should allow you to host ServiceStack in a sub-url, and it will not interfere with your existing controllers, unless there is a conflict in the path:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
```

The ServiceStack http handler in your web.config will need to match:

```
<location path="api">
<!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: The NuGet package did that for me by default.  The Service Stack services stuff hangs off of the /api.  However, the AppHost is still doing some stuff before my regular MVC app loads up....and it's this stuff that I'm trying to better understand.

Comment: What "stuff" does it do ? What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: The AppHost was loading and redirecting to default.htm, which I changed by setting the DefaultRedirectPath = "/Home".  I'll re-edit my question, but I just want to verify that the AppHost running before my global.aspx code is the proper order, and that setting my default redirectPath in the appropriate way to start the integration into existing MVC site code.  I'm spending a lot of time with the SocialBootstrapApi to try and understand all this.  Even though I'm hanging the SS handler off of /api, I still want to be able to integrate the AppHost stuff into my regular app.

Comment: OK, I think I figured out what I was missing, I needed to set the CatchAllController per BootstrapAPI application: eServiceStackController.CatchAllController = reqCtx => container.TryResolve<HomeController>();   This seems to fix the default controller issue, and prepares me to have the Funq container   working with my existing controllers.